# How to modify LastAccess time attribute of a file

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have implemented the following function which changes the LastAccess time of a file to the latest time of the current system but however, I wanted it to change the LastAccess time to a customized time. for example, I give a time like 1994-04-04 to the function, and then it changes the LastAccess time to that time.

```
BOOL SetFileToCurrentTime(const char* arg_path, const char* arg_file_name)
{
    HANDLE h_File;
    FILETIME ft_FileTime;
    SYSTEMTIME st_SystemTime;

    char l_c_Path[MAX_PATH];

    strcpy(l_c_Path, arg_path);
    strcat(l_c_Path, arg_file_name);

    h_File = CreateFile(l_c_Path, FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    GetSystemTime(&st_SystemTime);                          // Gets the current system time
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&st_SystemTime, &ft_FileTime);     // Converts the current system time to file time format

    if (SetFileTime(h_File, &ft_FileTime, &ft_FileTime, &ft_FileTime))
    {
        CloseHandle(h_File);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    CloseHandle(h_File);
}
```

How should I modify the above code to achieve the goal?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I modify your code a little bit to achieve the goal. If you want to change LastAccess of file, you have to set this value only and set the other parameters to NULL.

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL SetFileToCurrentTime(LPCTSTR lpFileName) {
    HANDLE hFile;
    FILETIME ft;
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;
    DWORD dwLastErr = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    hFile = CreateFile(lpFileName, FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        // Cannot open this file
        return FALSE;
    }

    GetSystemTime(&st); // Gets the current system time
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &ft); // Converts the current system time to file time format

    // set new LastAccess Time
    if (!(bResult = SetFileTime(hFile, NULL, &ft, NULL))) {
        dwLastErr = GetLastError();
    }

    CloseHandle(hFile);
    SetLastError(dwLastErr);
    return bResult;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 2) {
        if (SetFileToCurrentTime(argv[1])) {
            printf("Success\n");
        } else {
            printf("Failed! Last Error = %d\n", GetLastError());
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SystemTimeToFileTime()` [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-systemtimetofiletime?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to get your requested date into the right format that you can pass into the `SetFileTime()` function.